# Strange text when converting XML array to XML

Tags: php

Im using the answer to this question to convert an array of XML to a single XML output:

[Output array of XML to plain XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554671/output-array-of-xml-to-plain-xml)

Im using the simpler solution of the two there (Marked as the answer)

It all works for me, however at the start of the output I get:

```
string(109960) "
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Can you share the snippet? It might be that you are using Var_dump() somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are using **[`var_dump`](http://fr.php.net/var_dump)** to output your XML string :

```
var_dump($xml);
```

Instead of just using **[`echo`](http://fr.php.net/echo)** :

```
echo $xml;
```

It would explain :

- The quotes arround the whole XML string
- The `string` -- which is the type of the variable passed as a parameter to `var_dump`
- The `109960` -- which is the length of your string.

`var_dump()` is useful ; but should only be used **when you are debugging**, as it outputs more *(debugging)* informations than just the content of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is being `var_dump`(ed). If there is a `var_dump` keyword, you should remove it.